# What is Istio best way to create gateway based on dev, uat and production environment

Tags: azure, kubernetes, istio

I'm currently creating a K8s cluster using Azure + Istio for our developers. At this moment I'm focusing on dev and UAT... I'm a bit stuck on this part, as we'll be deploying micro service components and also older windows applications I want to set up a dev and UAT environment so developers can access env.xyz.com/appname.

I've set the gateway:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: dev-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "dev.xyz.com"
    - "uat.xyz.com"
```

So, my next question is when a developer creates a deployment how can I with `virtualService` just automatically based on app name create uri.

```
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /appname
```

Or do we have to create a virtual service for each deploy?